# How do I trouble shoot an Apache 500 Internal Server Error? (restart, status, tail... then what?)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server, command-line-interface, 500-error

Here's what I've done so far

```
[username@VMname /]$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
[username@VMname /]$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[username@VMname /]$ /etc/init.d/httpd status
httpd (pid  23043) is running...
```

Then tried running...

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error.log
```

That returned file not found, so I looked and this is what I see:

```
[username@VMname /]$ cd /var/log/httpd
access_log  access_log.1  error_log  error_log.1  ssl_access_log  ssl_error_log  ssl_error_log.1  ssl_request_log
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

not error.log

Check your apache config file for a line with

```
LogLevel
```

I would suggest

```
LogLevel error
```

until you figure out the error.  warn/debug might be too verbose